# Android libraries for ffmpeg + stagefright. language c++

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg, stagefright

I'v making cross-platform program **in c++**. In my program for Android platform i need video decoding hw acceleration. I have found out, that I need to look in libstagefright.cpp. which contains ffmpeg library. There I have found next includes:

```
#include <binder/ProcessState.h>
#include <media/stagefright/MetaData.h>
#include <media/stagefright/MediaBufferGroup.h>
#include <media/stagefright/MediaDebug.h>
#include <media/stagefright/MediaDefs.h>
#include <media/stagefright/OMXClient.h>
#include <media/stagefright/OMXCodec.h>
#include <utils/List.h>
```

Also, I found out that the source code of these headers is here: https://android.googlesource.com . But I can't understand in which way to build them. So, my question is: **Where can i get these libraries or how can get the source code, that i need to build?** Also, I look for advice which way I can better use Android video decoding hw acceleration + ffmpeg.

Comment: see 'build AOSP' ... https://source.android.com/source/building.html

Comment: the resources in your list don't touch upon ffmpeg